# Populate one dropdownlist value based on the selection of the value on other drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

I have 2 dropdown lists. The first one contains the list of Users. And the second one contains the list of the Phone numbers. So when i select a name from the First dropdown list the phone number of the corresponding user should be selected from the second drop down list .When i change the selection on first dropdown the page is realoading again but the eent is not triggering. Below is the code i tried.

Thanks

ASPX code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="top">
            <div class="fieldLbls" style="text-align: right;">
                <label>Users :</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="UserDDL" Width="175px" runat="server"
                              OnSelectIndexChanged="User_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <label>Phone No :</label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="PhoneNoDD1" Width="175px" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code on aspx.xs

```
protected void User_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PhoneNoDD1.ClearSelection();// giving a try whether its triggering or not to clear selection but not triggering
}
```

Comment: Is `User_SelectedIndexChanged()` triggering?

Comment: Do you have aspx mapped to the correct code-behind file ? Because, your code is okay.

Comment: yes it mapped other events are triggering for other buttons correctly

Comment: @devlincarnate the event is not trigerring

Comment: Can you include in the question the code where you populate `UserDDL`? Is it in `Page_Load` and, if so, is it inside `if (!IsPostBack)`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  Something else must be interfering with the event.  There are a good number of posts about this on Stack Overflow.  I suggest you review them to find the solution that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

When UserDDL selected index changed update the selected value of PhoneNoDD1.

```
protected void User_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PhoneNoDD1.SelectedValue = value;
}
```

Comment: Its not triggering this method at all dont know why